Cartoon movie that had mercenaries and weapons merge
I vaguely remember some cartoon, I believe it was a movie, from the 80's or 90's most likely, and there's only one scene I remember.  Medieval fantasy setting, there are these typical bad guy henchmen types fighting for an evil witch, maybe wizard.  At one point she conjures up some green liquid, and the henchmen end up going into it with their weapons, and come out with the weapons as part of their body.  I believe one had like clubs instead of hands, and one had an axe head instead of a normal head.
That's almost all I can remember.

Sounds like what villain Ruber does to his henchmen in the animated Quest for Camelot from 1998.

Using a [green] magic potion he obtained from some witches, Baron Ruber fuses a chicken with an axe to form Bladebeak and fuses different weapons to his followers.

The magic is broken near the end and the men return to normal. Here's the scene you're describing (the relevant bit starts around 2:35):




That's it! Thank you!  I was off about some things, but 16 years will do that to you.
